# Access multiple database using linq in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq

I want to use multiple databases which are in different servers using linq.

I'm new to this. pls anyone help me.

I'm having all the connectionstrings i wanted in one table. Dynamically i want to access different db using linq.
Is it possible?

here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < chkSchool.Items.Count; i++)
{
      if (chkSchool.Items[i].Selected)
      {
           school = com.GetSchoolNames(chkType.SelectedItem.ToString(), chkSchool.Items[i].Text);
           foreach (var item in school.ToList())
           {
               entity.dbconnection = item.DatabaseConn;
               Session["dbconnection"] = entity.dbconnection;
           }
           string news = data.GetNews(Convert.ToInt32(chkYear.SelectedItem.ToString()));
           string result = data.GetResult(chkYear.SelectedItem.ToString());
     }
}
```

Each school has different db connection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem? Don't hardcode your connections, but rather switch them as needed on fly... Providing a different connection string isn't  hard at all. If you want further assistance, maybe try to show what have you tried and what didn't work as expected.

Comment: I'm using more than 10 databases. how can i give all the connection strings?

Comment: Can you provide an example what are you trying to do, what have you tried and what didn't work? It doesn't really make much sense so far, at least not to me.

Comment: What is the type of a variable `entity`? Do these databases have exactly the same table structure? Do you use Linq2Sql or Linq2EF?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is not possible from LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities. `DataContext` and `DbContext` can only target a single database when they are instantiated. You would have to create another instance targeting a different database but this is a disconnected approach between the entities retrieved.

The only way I have achieved this is by having a central database referencing all the tables across all the databases by using synonyms. Having this you can target the central db and this will reach out to all your tables across databases. The good thing about synonyms is they you can execute all the CRUD operations and they are dispatched to the real table. You can actually map any object using synonyms (tables, views, function, store procs) and bring them together into a single DB.
Also executing queries with joins on tables in different tables across DB's like you would do in SSMS are possible.

Now, you would run into a problem if all your databases have the same structure. This approach is for databases with different structure and you want to bring the structures to talk to each other from a business perspective.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**
Lets say you have `DB1.dbo.Products` and `DB2.dbo.Shipments` tables. As you can see they live in 2 different databases. The solution I'm talking about would need a 3rd database (`ALL_DBs`) and you would create synonyms on it for the 2 tables above like this:

```
USE ALL_DBs
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.Products FOR DB1.dbo.Products
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.Shipments FOR DB2.dbo.Shipments
```

As you can see the data is still stored in `DB1` and `DB2` but you can access them from the same context if you target `ALL_DBs` because it has pointers to other objects in other databases.
Now you can have a single DbContext or DataContext pointing to `ALL_DBs` and you would be able to query both tables at the same time.

Comment: sorry... I'm new to this. Can u elaborate or give me some example how to reference table across multiple db using synonyms.

Comment: thanks for ur reply.. but am having same structure for all database.

Comment: Then there is no way for L2S or L2E to target all these databases with the same context instance. You will need to a separate context for every database as explained above. I would recommend creating another database that provides views that gather data from all databases, but it would only be for reading purposes.